# How to extract the underlying coefficients from fitting a linear b spline regression in R?

Tags: r, regression, bspline

Take for instance the following one-knot, degree one, spline:

```
library(splines)
library(ISLR)

age.grid    = seq(range(Wage$age)[1], range(Wage$age)[2])
fit.spline  = lm(wage~bs(age, knots=c(30), degree=1), data=Wage)
pred.spline = predict(fit.spline, newdata=list(age=age.grid), se=T)

plot(Wage$age, Wage$wage, col="gray")
lines(age.grid, pred.spline$fit, col="red")

# NOTE: This is **NOT** the same as fitting two piece-wise linear models becase
# the spline will add the contraint that the function is continuous at age=30
# fit.1  = lm(wage~age, data=subset(Wage,age<30))
# fit.2  = lm(wage~age, data=subset(Wage,age>=30))
```

[image: Spline Plot]

Is there a way to extract the linear model (and its coefficients) for before and after the knot?  That is, how can I extract the two linear models before and after the cut point of `age=30`?

Using `summary(fit.spline)` yields coefficients, but (to my understanding) they are not meaningful for interpretation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the coefficients manually from `fit.spline` like this

```
summary(fit.spline)

Call:
lm(formula = wage ~ bs(age, knots = 30, degree = 1), data = Wage)
Coefficients:
                                 Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                         54.19       4.05    13.4   <2e-16 ***
bs(age, knots = 30, degree = 1)1    58.43       4.61    12.7   <2e-16 ***
bs(age, knots = 30, degree = 1)2    68.73       4.54    15.1   <2e-16 ***
---

range(Wage$age)
## [1] 18 80
## coefficients of the first model
a1 <- seq(18, 30, length.out = 10)
b1 <- seq(54.19, 58.43+54.19, length.out = 10)
## coefficients of the second model
a2 <- seq(30, 80, length.out = 10)
b2 <- seq(54.19 + 58.43, 54.19 + 68.73, length.out = 10)
plot(Wage$age, Wage$wage, col="gray", xlim = c(0, 90))
lines(x = a1, y = b1, col = "blue" )
lines(x = a2, y = b2, col = "red")
```

### [image]

If you want the coefficients of the slope like in a linear model then you can simply use

```
b1 <- (58.43)/(30 - 18)
b2 <- (68.73 - 58.43)/(80 - 30)
```

Note that in `fit.spline` the intercept means the value of `wage` when `age = 18` whereas in a linear model the intercept means the value `wage` when `age = 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Extracting the knots is primarily done when you pre-specify degrees of freedom in your bspline regression.  Example:

> fit.spline  = lm(wage~bs(age, df=5), data=Wage)
>
> attr(bs(age,df=5),"knots")
>
> > 33.33333% 66.66667%
> >
> > ```
> >   37        48
> > ```

An example can be found in the ISLR book (which you appear to be using) on page 293.